# HmacSHA256 Encoding in java

Tags: java

I just want to encode a given string to HmacSHA256 according to a private key in java.anyone can provide a simple program....?

Answer (score 4):

```
SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[20];
    sr.nextBytes(keyBytes);
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA1");
    Mac m = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    m.init(key);
    m.update(inputData);
    byte[] mac = m.doFinal();
```

Copied from 'http://oreilly.com/catalog/javacrypt/chapter/ch06.html', you'll find all other cryptographic information there.